# validation for checkboxes not working

Tags: php, laravel-5.6

I have the following HTML code,

```
<div class="col-md-8 address-proof">
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        {{ Form::checkbox('Proof[]', 1, true, array('class' => 'form-check-input')) }}
        <label class="form-check-label" for="Passport">Passport</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline conditional"  data-condition="['yes'].includes(HaveAadharCard)">
        {{ Form::checkbox('Proof[]', 2, false, array('class' => 'form-check-input')) }}
        <label class="form-check-label" for="Adhaar">Adhaar</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        {{ Form::checkbox('Proof[]', 3, false, array('class' => 'form-check-input','id'=>'DrivingL')) }}
        <label class="form-check-label" for="DL">DL </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        {{ Form::checkbox('Proof[]', 4, false, array('class' => 'form-check-input')) }}
        <label class="form-check-label" for="Voter_Id">Voter ID</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        {{ Form::checkbox('Proof[]', 5, false, array('class' => 'form-check-input')) }}
        <label class="form-check-label" for="NREGA">NREGA</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I have the following validation code,

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'title' => 'required',
    'body' => 'required',
     ...        
    'Proof' => 'required|min:2',    
]);
```

The above code is not working, I want at least two check boxes mandatory.

UPDATE:

I had to add

```
{{ Form::hidden('Proof', 0) }}
```

field to get it work.

Comment: use 'array|required|min:2' instead of 'required|min:2'

Comment: @rawathemant, Tried that too. that only works when I select one item.